# flink: sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING ) error: "not found: value Order"

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am running the following code and getting "error: not found: value Order"
I am not able to figure out a reason. What am I doing wrong?

version : Flink v 0.9.1 (hadoop 1) not using hadoop: Local execution shell: scala shell

```
Scala-Flink> val data_avg = data_split.map{x=> ((x._1), (x._2._2/x._2._1))}.sortPartition(1, Order.ASCENDING).setParallelism(1)
<console>:16: error: not found: value Order
            val data_avg = data_split.map{x=> ((x._1), (x._2._2/x._2._1))}.sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING).setParallelism(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the enum `Order` is not automatically imported by Flink's Scala shell. Therefore, you have to add the following import manually.

```scala
import org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.Order
```

Comment: Thank You Very much. I am new to Flink, can you please point me to documentation that will tell me whats if automatically imported to scala shell and what is not?

Comment: Actually this is not properly documented as far as I know. I've created an issue to fix this problem by automatically importing everything from the Java API. You can find the corresponding JIRA here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2774